# Create an array from content in string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that takes multiple key values and i would like to get these value and create an array from it.

The string will be built the same way but might contain more keys or less keys. An example of a string is this

```
"title:'this is the new title', msg:'this_is_updated', body:'this is the new body text'
```

So i need some way to to turn these keys from the string into an array that looks like this

```
$array['customMessage'] = [
  'title' => 'this is the new title',
  'msg' => 'this_is_updated',
  'body' => 'this is the new body'
];
```

Comment: does the string in json format?

Comment: if its json, use `json_decode(yourString, true);`

Comment: It looks like the only difference between your current string format and JSON format is that you need { at the beginning and } at the end...I'd try converting it to json format and then using json_decode like @AseemUpadhyay suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its allways in this format

```
key: val, key:val
```

as you have showed then use explode

```
$str = "title:'this is the new title', msg:'this_is_updated', body:'this is the 
new body text'";
foreach(explode(',', $str) as $val)
{
    $item = explode(':', $val);
    $array['customMessage'][trim($item[0])] = trim($item[1],"'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should always try to use an already existing format. JSON is perfect for that, for example, and PHP has already existing functions to work with that.

If that's not possible, for whatever reason, you can use the following to achive your result string:

```
$string = "title:'this is the new title', msg:'this_is_updated', body:'this is the new body text'";

$firstExplode = explode(',', $string);

foreach($firstExplode as $explode) {
  $val = explode(':', $explode);
  $arr[$val[0]] = $val[1];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(23) "'this is the new title'"
  [" msg"]=>
  string(17) "'this_is_updated'"
  [" body"]=>
  string(27) "'this is the new body text'"
}
```

Comment: same logic we have use...hahha

Answer (score 0):

this is the logic

```
$str = "title:'this is the new title', msg:'this_is_updated', body:'this is the new body text' ";
        $str1 = explode(',', $str);
        $array['customMessage'] = array();
        foreach ($str1 as $key => $value) {
            $str2 = explode(':', $value);

            $array['customMessage'][$str2[0]] = $str2[1];
        }


        print_r($array['customMessage']);die;
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can build the string in a JSON format and use json_decode() like this:

```
$json = '{
    "title":"this is the new title",
    "msg":"this_is_updated",
    "body":"this is the new body text"
}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$arrayFinal = array();
$arrayFinal['customMessage'] = $array;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayFinal);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will give the following output:

```
Array
(
    [customMessage] => Array
        (
            [title] => this is the new title
            [msg] => this_is_updated
            [body] => this is the new body text
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is a simple JSON object, just decode with this native function

`$array = json_decode($string)`